# calc: how to specify radix while yanking

Tags: calc

I know I can [yank into the stack](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Yanking-Into-Stack) in `calc` using `C-y`.  However, it seems that `calc` automatically assumes that I'm yanking in a base-10 number.  If I try to specify a radix (like `16#` for hex) before yanking and *then* pressing `C-y` I get the error message `[Bad format]` from [`(calcDigit-nondigit)`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/671974ef79012c8123182a0990c6d5580f53311a/lisp/calc/calc.el#L2367).

If I actually prefix my killed text with `16#` then it works, but that's a little tedious.  Is there any way to tell `calc` "hey, I'm about to yank a number of base `n`"?

---

Concrete examples:

#### (1) yank a hex number with hex set as `calc`'s default radix *(doesn't work)*

1. Kill the following text: `deadbeef`
2. Switch to a `calc` buffer
3. Make hex the default radix with `d 6`
4. Hit `C-y`

#### (2) yank a hex number, with radix prefix typed into calc minibuffer *(doesn't work)*

1. Kill the following text: `deadbeef`
2. Switch to a `calc` buffer
3. Tell `calc` that we're about to enter a hex number by typing `16#`
4. Hit `C-y`

#### (3) yank a hex number along with the necessary `calc` radix prefix *(works)*

1. Kill the following text: `16#deadbeef`
2. Switch to a `calc` buffer
3. Hit `C-y`

(3) works, but I'd like to get either (1) or (2) working.  If (3) is the only option I guess I'll write my own function to prepend my last kill with a `calc` radix prefix...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do that since the string `deadbeef` is a valid Calc identifier, i.e. it could just name a variable or a function, so it would be wrong to interpret it as a number.

Comment: Hmm, but if I type `16#deadbeef` it doesn't interpret it as an identifier... Why does it do so when I yank the text `deadbeef` after typing `16#`?

Comment: An identifier syntax must start with a non-digit, while number must start with a digit. It's a bit more complex than that (punctuation etc), but for this example it should explain the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update (Oct 12 2015)

**Below `calc-yank` implementation is now [added to emacs trunk](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=ec0d4d24fd11b5040de9f7657b486c3b1e743071).**

It will be available in the next stable emacs release.

---

I reviewed the original definition of `calc-yank` and the good thing is that it does not have any argument. So I added my own argument, `radix`, and slightly modified how the let-bound var `thing` is derived.

By default, the below modified function will work the exact same as the original `calc-yank`.

But if you want to yank the value in the kill ring as a hexadecimal number, you will be able to now do so now by doing `C-u 6 C-y` or `C-6 C-y` or `M-6 C-y`.

To test it, copy `1000` to the kill-ring.

Then,

- `C-2 C-y` will paste `8` (`2#1000`),
- `C-8 C-y` will paste `512` (`8#1000`),
- `C-0 C-y` will paste `1000` (`10#1000`),
- `C-6 C-y` will paste `4096` (`16#1000`)

.. and `C-y` will paste `1000` (`1000`).

```el
(defun calc-yank (radix)
          "Yank a value into the Calculator buffer.

Valid numeric prefixes for RADIX: 0, 2, 6, 8
No radix notation is prepended for any other numeric prefix.

If RADIX is 2, prepend \"2#\"  - Binary.
If RADIX is 8, prepend \"8#\"  - Octal.
If RADIX is 0, prepend \"10#\" - Decimal.
If RADIX is 6, prepend \"16#\" - Hexadecimal.

If RADIX is a non-nil list (created using \\[universal-argument]), the user
will be prompted to enter the radix in the minibuffer.

If RADIX is nil or if the yanked string already has a calc radix prefix, the
yanked string will be passed on directly to the Calculator buffer without any
alteration."
          (interactive "P")
          (calc-wrapper
           (calc-pop-push-record-list
            0 "yank"
            (let* (radix-num
                   radix-notation
                   valid-num-regexp
                   (thing-raw
                    (if (fboundp 'current-kill)
                        (current-kill 0 t)
                      (car kill-ring-yank-pointer)))
                   (thing
                    (if (or (null radix)
                            ;; Match examples: -2#10, 10\n(10#10,01)
                            (string-match-p "^[-(]*[0-9]\\{1,2\\}#" thing-raw))
                        thing-raw
                      (progn
                        (if (listp radix)
                            (progn
                              (setq radix-num
                                    (read-number
                                     "Set radix for yanked content (2-36): "))
                              (when (not (and (integerp radix-num)
                                              (<= 2 radix-num)
                                              (>= 36 radix-num)))
                                (error (concat "The radix has to be an "
                                               "integer between 2 and 36."))))
                          (setq radix-num
                                (cond ((eq radix 2) 2)
                                      ((eq radix 8) 8)
                                      ((eq radix 0) 10)
                                      ((eq radix 6) 16)
                                      (t (message
                                          (concat "No radix prepended "
                                                  "for invalid *numeric* "
                                                  "prefix %0d.")
                                          radix)
                                         nil))))
                        (if radix-num
                            (progn
                              (setq radix-notation
                                    (concat (number-to-string radix-num) "#"))
                              (setq valid-num-regexp
                                    (cond
                                     ;; radix 2 to 10
                                     ((and (<= 2 radix-num)
                                           (>= 10 radix-num))
                                      (concat "[0-"
                                              (number-to-string (1- radix-num))
                                              "]+"))
                                     ;; radix 11
                                     ((= 11 radix-num) "[0-9aA]+")
                                     ;; radix 12+
                                     (t
                                      (concat "[0-9"
                                              "a-" (format "%c" (+ 86 radix-num))
                                              "A-" (format "%c" (+ 54 radix-num))
                                              "]+"))))
                              ;; Ensure that the radix-notation is prefixed
                              ;; correctly even for multi-line yanks like below,
                              ;;   111
                              ;;   1111
                              (replace-regexp-in-string
                               valid-num-regexp
                               (concat radix-notation "\\&")
                               thing-raw))
                          thing-raw)))))
              (if (eq (car-safe calc-last-kill) thing)
                  (cdr calc-last-kill)
                (if (stringp thing)
                    (let ((val (math-read-exprs (calc-clean-newlines thing))))
                      (if (eq (car-safe val) 'error)
                          (progn
                            (setq val (math-read-exprs thing))
                            (if (eq (car-safe val) 'error)
                                (error "Bad format in yanked data")
                              val))
                        val))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

```
Is there any way to tell calc "hey, I'm about to yank a number of base n"?
```

Unfortunately no. In the Calc manual I found this:

```
Numbers are not stored with any particular radix attached.
```

However, you could try storing and yanking from registers.

```
r i (calc-insert-register)
```